# Excel shorten formula

Tags: excel, vba

Hi i have an excel document with cells spread out like this:

```
A * *
B E *
C F *
D G *
```

I need to add thease to a cell like this A**BE*CF*DG*

I can't use this formula

```
=A1&B1&C1&A2&B2&C2&A3&B3&C3&A4&B4&C4
```

I need to find a shorter way of doing this any suggestions would be appreciated I have started this in VBA:

```
Sub com()
    Dim x
    Set x = Range("A1:A4", "B1:B4", "C1:C4")
End Sub
```

I am not experienced with this, If anyone could help me on how to output this to a msgbox or put it into a cell in a basic way that would be much appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: http://www.excel-easy.com/vba.html

Comment: @simoco Thanks that might come in handy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you started:

```
Sub com()

    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim lCol As Long
    Dim sOutput as String

    For lRow = 1 to 4 'Change start and end rows as necessary
        For lCol =  Columns("A").Column to Columns("C").Column 'Change start and end columns as necessary
            sOutput = sOutput & Cells(lRow, lCol).Text
        Next lCol
    Next lRow

    MsgBox sOutput

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Without VBA, add a blank row at the top and in say D2 copied down:

```
=D1&A2&B2&C2
```